# How can I do this using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

The SQL query is as follows,

```
select s1.* 
from Sample1 s1,Sample2 s2 where
s1.field1=s2.field4 and
s2.field2='XXYYZZ'
```

Table Structure

- The table Sample1 has only three fields ( field1, field2, field3 )
- The table Sample2 has three fields ( field4, field5, field6 )

And the Bean Names are

`Sample1Bean`, `Sample2Bean`

I want the data only from the Sample1 only, (field1, field2, field3). How can I do this using Hibernate without HQL and Using Criteria class?

Comment: Whether my question is not clear? thats why I m not getting response?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT s1 FROM Sample1 s1, Sample2 s2 WHERE s1.field1 = s2.field2 AND s2.field2 = 'XXYYZZ'
```

It will return object of type Sample1 as result.

Answer (score 0):

```
List s1 = session.createCriteria(Sample1.class)
                 .createCriteria("field1")
                 .add(Restrictions.eq("field2", "XXYYZZ")).
                 .list();
```

Hibernate make queries on objects not on table. So the association between Sample1 and Sample2 should be mapped.

Obs:

1. s1 will have a list of Sample1.
2. "field1" should be a attribute in Sample1 of type Sample2.

Comment: I think you missed this condition - `s1.field1=s2.field4`.

Comment: Nope, the association between Sample1 and Sample2 should be mapped... `s1.field1=s2.field4` is the join condition and should in the mapping configuration :)